# How to disable transparent window decorations at a GPU level in KDE?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, performance, desktop-environments

I'm runnig Ubuntu with KDE (originally installed Ubuntu and renamed itself Kubuntu after install of KDE) and I'm trying to improve the performance of my computer. It runs well but I'm a bit pushing it far with IntelliJ and Chrome running simultaneously. So for me, the more performance the better.

On Windows computer, you can enable/disable Windows Aero and disabling it is a good idea if you have a weak computer since it consumes less.

Is it the same for KDE ? Is there a way to disable transparency other than just selecting a simple theme to improve performance ? If there's any other way to decrease the weight my desktop environment is having on my computer, I would like to know. I don't care about having windows looking like 1990.

PS: I already have unchecked all the desktop effects.

Comment: if you have performance issues with KDE due to your system lacking power check the minimum requirements. If those are near to your system opt for another version: lUbuntu of xUbuntu. Changes to themes are only going to be minor improvements. Changing the DE is a far better improvement for speed.